# How to add the JSF 2.0 plugin to eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, java-web-start

I want to make a "Hello World" app on eclipse using jsf config. I couldn't find the link to install the plugin!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the eclipse in "Help" -> Install New Software-> Add the following addres to the update site of jboss tools "http://download.jboss.org/jbosstools/updates/stable/kepler".

In this case I'm using the eclipse Kepler the newest version of eclipse, you have to verify which eclipse version you have before download.

Select the Option "Jboss Web and Java EE Development" when you see the available software for update.

Answer (score 0):

Download the Java Enterprise Edition Package for eclipse instead.

It has the jsf stuff included already.

usually 2nd from top on the list [here](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/)